CACHE_RESULT or variable
I am wondering what would be better between using a variable or RESULT_CACHE?
For example:
declare
  v_last_date date;
begin
  select last_date 
    into v_last_date 
    from my_table_1;

  update my_table_2 
     set col_1 = col_1 * 10 
   where col_2_date > v_last_date;

  .... same for my_table_3, my_table_4, ... my_table_100
  commit;
end;

or
begin
  update my_table_2 
     set col_1 = col_1 * 10 
   where col_2_date > (select /*+ RESULT_CACHE*/ last_date 
                         from my_table_1);

  .... same for my_table_3, my_table_4, ... my_table_100
  commit;
end;

Thank you,

As the both option provide a different result they are not comparable.  Cache does not guarantee the same result. Despite this you'll see no difference as the table_1 has apparently only one row (hopefully one block only) so the mass elapsed time will be in the updates.

Use the variable. This shows precisely what you do: When starting the PL/SQL block you look at the date and use it then throughout your routine.
The cache on the other hand is a more complex matter. In every query you'd select the date found in that moment in my_table_1. You speed this up by using /*+ RESULT_CACHE*/, but still, the DBMS will have to search the cache, which can't be as fast as simply using the variable. Additionally the DBMS must manage that cache. If there is a write access to the date table, then the cache will be invalidated. This can mean that when another process deletes old data not affecting the maximum date, the DBMS will still invalidate the cache to play safe, and the date query must be run again.
Using a subquery can also mean that the date changes while running the routine, and the first query would work with another date than the last query in the block.

Are you sure on that final paragraph? When Oracle starts a transaction, all the queries will give the result as per the state at the start of the transaction (unless the current transaction modifies a row, when you will see the changes from the current transaction). Therefore, I do not believe that you will see the effects of any other transaction modifying the state of the table.

@MT0: Yes, I am sure. Each query looks at the data as of the very moment the query starts. In Oracle you are always in  a transaction, by the way. Imagine to start a session that only reads data and you keep using it for several days. Do you really expect a query run on day x to return the data as it was many days ago on day 1?

@MT0: Maybe you are confusing it with running a single query for hours or days. This will read the data as of the query start time, and it can even fail when too much data has changed and the query is not able to reconstruct what the data looked like (ORA-01555: snapshot too old).

See Statement-Level Read Consistency - "In a serializable or read-only transaction, this point is the time the transaction began. For example, if a transaction begins at SCN 1000, and if multiple SELECT statements occur in this transaction, then each statement is consistent to SCN 1000."

You are updating so maybe this won't apply, but for some transactions, yes, even if they last multiple days then the SELECT will get the value from the start of the transaction.

@MT0: Okay, I've never come across this type of transaction. I don't even know how I would establish such a transaction. But it is good to know such thing exists. Thank you.

A better quote is probably the Transaction-Level Read Consistency "each statement in a transaction sees data from the same point in time. This is the time at which the transaction began. Queries made by a serializable transaction see changes made by the transaction itself. For example, a transaction that updates employees and then queries employees will see the updates."

@MT0 The default isolation level Oracle provides is statement-level consistency.  At that level, two queries in the same transaction will be consistent as of different SCNS.  If you want the behavior of transaction-level, you need to issue a SET TRANSACTION READ ONLY.  SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE is similar: it guarantees an error if transaction-level consistency is violated.
See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SET-TRANSACTION.html#SQLRF01705.
